# Perl: Getting two randomly selected variables from array to print on the same line

Tags: perl

The answer is probably right in front of me...but I've pulled too much of my hair out on this one. I have a script that reads in a list of first names and last names, stores them in arrays, then randomly picks 10 first and last names to print. For example, it will print "John Doe." after grabbing the first and last names. I have everything working, but the program isn't printing them on the same line. It's automaticlly making a new line, like this:

```
John
Doe
```

Here is the script:

```
use strict;

#Open boy names
my $boyFile = "boyFirst.txt"; 
open (FH, "< $boyFile") or die "Can not open $boyFile for read: $!"; 
my @allNames; 
while (<FH>) # While file is open, keep putting new lines into list
{
    push (@allNames, $_);
}
close FH or die "Can not close $boyFile: $!";

#open girl names
my $girlFile = "girlFirst.txt";
open (FH, "< $girlFile") or die "Can not open $girlFile for read: $!";
#my @girlLines;
while (<FH>) 
{
    push (@allNames, $_); # While file is open, keep putting new lines into list
}
close FH or die "Can not close $girlFile: $!";

#open last names
my $lastFile = "lastName.txt";
open (FH, "< $lastFile") or die "Can not open $lastFile for read: $!";
my @lastLines;
while (<FH>) 
{
    push (@lastLines, $_); # While file is open, keep putting new lines into list
}
close FH or die "Can not close $lastFile: $!";

#Generate Alphabet
my @alpha = ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z');

my $name;
my $lastName;
my $randomFirstName;
my $randomLastName;

for (1 .. 10)
{
    $name = rand @allNames;
    $lastName = rand @lastLines;
    $randomFirstName = $allNames[$name];
    $randomLastName = $lastLines[$lastName];
    printf("$randomFirstName");
    printf("$randomLastName");


}
```

Tips, and advice are also appreciated. New to scripting :)

Comment: You need to [chomp](http://p3rl.org/chomp) the input.

Comment: BTW, `my @alpha = 'A' .. 'Z';` is way shorter.

Comment: Also, you don't need $name, $lastName etc. outside the loop, so don't declare it with unnecessarily wide scope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `chomp;` before all your `push` statements. It will remove the line ending character from `$_` before it is pushed to arrays. Then add a `print "\n";` after the final `print` statement.